# PHP, Doctrine, use join with different "where" and "on"

Tags: php, mysql, sql, doctrine-orm

I've a custom repository that fetch an entity. I want to add an inner join to the query to do some research based on the linked data. But i need to do separate ON and Where.
If i do something like this

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder($this->talias)
      ->add('where', 'conditions')
      ->join('Repository:OtherEntity', 'c');
```

The condition I was defined using ->add('where', 'conditions') will transform in the join ON:

```
SELECT records FROM table1 alias INNER JOIN OtherTable c ON( conditions )
```

but the result i need is

```
SELECT records FROM table1 alias INNER JOIN OtherTable c ON( ONconditions ) WHERE conditions
```

What is the way ?
Thanks

Comment: try adding the where after the join

Comment: already tried, it become the join ON and the previous where disappear

Answer (score 1):

Ok, solved, just need to add extra parameters to the join method

```
$qb->join("Entity", 'prefix', 'WITH', 'conditions');
```